# Can be fix our token price to a stock?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

For example can we create a pepsi token which is fix to pepsi stocks? Do you think that is useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example can we create a pepsi token which is fix to pepsi stocks?

This might be possible during the ICO/crowdsale phase using an oracle to grab the current value of the stock whenever someone buys some of your tokens.

Once the ICO/crowdsale is complete, and people can freely trade your token on the open market, then pegging its price to a stock would be more difficult. (Though presumably possible with the right token contract set-up to allow you to tightly control the supply.)

> Do you think that is useful?

Whether it's useful or not depends on why you want to actually do it in the first place...

Comment: With fix the stock i mean, as an example of one of the nasdaq stocks maybe?

Comment: The problem is that once people own your tokens, they can sell those tokens to each other for any price they like. (Or a price that the supply and demand of the market sets.) In order to fix your token's price, you would need to very carefully control the supply and demand of the token to balance the changes caused by the market. (Even if you did this, your token might be sold on different markets for different prices. I don't know how you would manipulate things to make the prices in those markets consistent.)